# Starting the redis server by javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

How to run the redis by script, instead of manual start using "redis-server" ...

Comment: why do you want to do that? why not run redis as a service as it should run? redis includes init script for linux distros and even an install script that configures them interactively.

Comment: this task would be useful for unit tests

Comment: @jermel Unit tests are meant to be run isolated, that means without any network/filesystem/database dependency. You should think about mocking your database access during unit tests to make them independent from environment.
Otherwise we are talking about integration tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [Execute a Unix Command with Node.js](https://dzone.com/articles/execute-unix-command-nodejs):

```
var sys = require('util')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    sys.puts(stdout)
}

exec("redis-server", puts);
```

Comment: Answer is here , with the help from kirilloid  :                  var sys = require('util')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("redis-server", puts);

Comment: The link is dead. That is the reason for the Stackoverflow guideline not to just paste links in here.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend that you do this over tcp.  This is a big security hole that you are opening.  There are plenty of tools for starting remote services over tcp.  Just to name a couple on unix Plexus and even ssh.

What is the biz requirement for this?

@Dvir Volk recommended using the start script and setting up redis as a service.